# Keras Save Model

Tags: python, keras

I imagine this is a stupid question, which means I'm just making a stupid mistake somewhere, but...
I made a simple neural network and want to save the model to load somewhere else with additional data, but every save model method I've been using has been giving me errors. Any help would be appreciated. The Keras FAQ article makes it sound simple. It may or may not be worth noting I'm running this code on Colab...

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model

def swish(x, beta = 1):
     return (x * sigmoid(beta * x))

get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})
dataset = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Cavity_Data_1/trainingData.csv")

#I have stuff going on here with normaliIng the dataset and assigning, splitting X and Y

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'swish', input_shape =(6,))) #WOOO!
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

optimizer_choice = optimizers.adam(lr=0.005) 
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer_choice, metrics=['mae']) 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 5, verbose = 1) 
model.summary()

model.save('my_model')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
```

The error message:
`AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-15-bc680e78a9aa> in <module>() 83 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model 84  ---> 85 model.save('my_model')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5' 86 del model 87`

And also this error:
`AttributeError: 'Activation' object has no attribute '__name__'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot save this model, because this part here is incorrect:

```
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})
```

Since you are using `"swish" as an activation function, it should not be a layer, so you just need to reference the function:

```
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': swish})
```

Then the model will train and can be saved successfully.

Comment: You are my idol. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

you can save by this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1) 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # train your model, then:
    savePath = saver.save(sess, 'someDir/my_model.ckpt')
```